# Simple java Process for opening files ends inexplicably

Tags: java, cmd, process

Part of my program needs to open files and documents, wait until user manually closes them and then deletes them. So I have a separate thread that just opens the file with Process class and waits for the Process to end, than it deletes the file. Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder ps=new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/C",path);
            Process p=ps.start();
            p.waitFor();
            ps=new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/C","del",path);
            p=ps.start();
            p.waitFor();
        }catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This works with pdf, txt or docx documents, but it doesn't work with images, the png or jpg files. In case of an image, thread opens the image with Windows Photos program but doesn't wait for process to end, instead it acts like the process is already dead and proceedes to delete it right after opening it, so instead of an image I see this:
[image]

My question is why does it act like the Process is immediately dead when I open PNG or JPG files, but it works normally when I open PDF, TXT, DOCX files? Is the problem in Windows Photos viewer maybe?

I managed to open image files adding

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

right after opening an image, but it still deletes the image after 5 seconds, it just somehow still stays open in Windows Photos viewer even if it has been deleted. Clearly this is not the solution, I want to properly solve this situation.

Comment: Why do you want to delete it right when the user closes it?

Comment: That's very brittle. Test what happens if there is no default application associated with PDF ... also, what I would be suspecting is that the Process that starts for images just starts another process (32 => 64 bit switch? Or vice versa?) and exits.

Comment: This could be down to how Windows Photos works: if the first process starts another process, then the first process quits, you'll only see that the first process has quit.

Comment: I was about to write the same comment as @Fildor. What you are attempting to do can be very counter-intuitive. My best guess is that the process spawns another process, hence the reason why you do not see your code wait for it.

Comment: Baseline: I'd really advise to use In-Process Viewers rather than relying on out-of-process default viewers that may or may not even be there on different systems.

Comment: @Fildor Well if Process starts another process when opening an image, and doesn't start another process when opening a textual document, then it must be something about Windows Photos which is used by the system to open images like Andy said in the comments.

Comment: @AndyTurner I will set another program to open images and then try again.

Comment: @rayDonovan Exactly.

Comment: Just to confirm, the problem was Windows Photos, other photo viewers or even paint work properly. Now why Windows Photos acts like that is a mistery.

Comment: @rayDonovan Not exactly a mistery. If I remeber correctly, (not 100% sure) by default, the 32 bit Version starts and checks if the system is 64 bit. If so, it hands over to its 64-bit version. (or something similar to that, but I may be mistaken. It's been a while since I had to deal with this)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file when your program exits. Why do you want that the File is delete right after the file is closed?

```
File file = new File("path");
file.deleteOnExit();
```

Comment: Becuse user is opening encrypted files, so I create a temporary decrypted file which user can view. Once user is done I can't leave a decrypted file remaining.

Comment: That makes sense, but what happens if some pdf viewer etc. have a build in history?

Comment: Hmm, to be honest I didn't even know there are such things. But I'm doing this for a University project and that's not the focus of the project anyway, I'm not going to distribute this program for use.

Comment: Even worse: By starting the default viewer to view that decrypted file, you open gates to attackers as wide as possible. 3 seconds to be pwned (not by me but a mildly determined script kiddie).

Comment: Interesting, do you maybe know a procedure of viewing encrypted files?

Comment: Do you use linux?